# voluptuous: list of dictionaries. full compliance

Tags: python, voluptuous

```
test_data = [{'field1': 'value1',
              'field2': 1},
             {'field1': 'value3',
              'field2': 2}
             ]


schema = Schema([
    {Required('field1'): 'value1',
     Required('field2'): int},
    {Required('field1'): 'value3',
     Required('field2'): int}
    
])

assert schema(test_data)
```

How to check that the list contains 2 dictionaries with the structure shown above? When I try to check for a full match, I get an error:
voluptuous.error.MultipleInvalid: not a valid value for dictionary value @ data[1]['field1']

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with voluptuous, but seems like it's not meant for parsing such schema without [voluptuous.ExactSequence](http://alecthomas.github.io/voluptuous/docs/_build/html/voluptuous.html#voluptuous.validators.ExactSequence)

Your schema would look like:

```
schema = Schema(
    ExactSequence(
        [
            {Required('field1'): 'value1', Required('field2'): int},
            {Required('field1'): 'value3', Required('field2'): int}
        ]
    ))
```